# Define a decision variable of M0 in CPLEX

Tags: python, numpy, constraints, cplex, docplex

Good day to you.
From a previous model with cplex (MIP 1), I use M0 as a parameter.

```
Total_P = 8
M0 = np.array([[0,1,0,1,0,0,0,2]]).reshape(Total_P,1)
```

Then, I tried to develop a different model (MIP 2) with adjusted objectives and constraints from MIP2, however, the M0 now becomes a decision variable and use for several constraints (#constraint 38). So, I created a code as follows:

```
Total_P = 8
M0 = np.empty((Total_P,1), dtype = object)
for l in range(0,Total_P):
    M0[l][0]= mdl.integer_var(name='M0'+ str(',') + str(l+1))


for l in range(0,Total_P):
    if M0[l][0] is not None:
        mdl.add_constraint((M0[1][0] + M0[5][0]) == 1)
        mdl.add_constraint((M0[3][0] + M0[6][0]) == 1)
        mdl.add_constraint((M0[0][0] + M0[2][0] + M0[4][0] + M0[7][0]) == 2)
```

After running the cplex with the same parameters input:

**The result from MIP 1:  obj_lambda=213**

**The result from MIP 2: obj_lamba= 205.0 and the M0 is [[0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1]]**

**The correct result of M0 from the MIP 2 should be [[0,1,0,1,0,0,0,2]] as in the M0 (parameter in MIP 1) and obj_lambda=213.**

Here is the full code of MIP 1:

```
import cplex
from docplex.mp.model import Model
import numpy as np

mdl = Model(name='Scheduling MIP 1')
inf = cplex.infinity
bigM= 10000

Total_P = 8 # number of places
Total_T = 6 # number of transitions

r1 = 100 #processing time for PM1 (second)
r2 = 200 #processing time for PM2 (second)

v = 3 #robot moving time (second)
w = 5 #loading or unloading time (second)

M0 = np.array([[0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1]]).reshape(Total_P,1)
M0_temp = M0.reshape(1,Total_P)
M0_final = M0_temp.tolist()*Total_T



h = np.array([v+w,w+r1,v+w,w+r2,v+w,0,0,0]).reshape(Total_P,1)

#Parameter
AT =np.array([[1,-1,0,0,0,0],
              [0,1,-1,0,0,0],
              [0,0,1,-1,0,0],
              [0,0,0,1,-1,0],
              [0,0,0,0,1,-1],
              [0,-1,1,0,0,0],
              [0,0,0,-1,1,0],
              [-1,1,-1,1,-1,1]])
AT_temp = AT.transpose()

places = np.array(['p1','p2','p3','p4','p5','p6','p7','p8'])
P_conflict = np.empty((1,Total_P), dtype = object)
P_zero = np.empty((1,Total_P), dtype = object)

#Define the place without conflict place
CP = np.count_nonzero(AT, axis=1, keepdims=True) #calculate the nonzero elements for each row
P_conflict = []
P_zero = []

for a in range(0, len(CP)):
    if CP[a].item(0) > 2:
        P_conflict.append(places[a])
    else:
        P_zero.append(places[a])

print('p_zero', np.shape(P_zero))

obj_lambda = [ ]
obj_lambda = mdl.continuous_var(lb = 0, ub=inf, name='obj_lambda')

x = np.array(mdl.continuous_var_list(Total_T, 0, inf, name='x')).reshape(Total_T,)
ind_x = np.where(AT[0] == 1)


print('ind_x', ind_x)

def get_index_value(input):
  data = []
  for l in range(len(P_zero)):
    ind_x = np.where(AT[l] == input)
    get_value = x[ind_x]
    data.append(get_value)
  return data


x_in = get_index_value(1)
x_out = get_index_value(-1)

#constraint 16
for l in range(0,len(P_zero)): #only for P non conflict
    #if x_in is not None and x_out is not None and obj_lambda is not None:
    mdl.add_constraint(x_out[l][0]-x_in[l][0] >= h[l][0] - M0[l][0]*obj_lambda)

#Decision Var
Z = np.empty((Total_T, Total_T), dtype = object)
for k in range(Total_T):
    for i in range(Total_T):
     Z[k][i] = mdl.binary_var(name='Z' + str(k+1) + str(',') + str(i+1))

storage_ZAT = []
for k in range(Total_T):
    ZAT = np.matmul(Z[k].reshape(1,Total_T),AT_temp)
    storage_ZAT.append(ZAT)    #storage_ZAT = np.append(storage_ZAT, ZAT, axis=0)

ZAT_final = np.asarray(storage_ZAT).reshape(Total_T,Total_P)

M = np.empty((Total_T, Total_P), dtype = object)
for k in range(0,Total_T):
    for l in range (0,Total_P):
        if k == Total_T-1:
            M[Total_T-1][l] = M0_final[0][l]
        else:
            M[k][l] = mdl.continuous_var(name='M' + str(k + 1) + str(',') + str(l + 1))

M_prev = np.empty((Total_T, Total_P), dtype = object)
if M is not None:
    for k in range(0,Total_T):
        for l in range (0,Total_P):
            if k is not 0:
                M_prev[k][l] = M[k-1][l]
            else:
                M_prev[0][l] = M0_final[0][l]

#Constraint 17
for k in range(Total_T):
  for l in range(Total_P):
          mdl.add_constraint(M[k][l] == M_prev[k][l] + ZAT_final[k][l])


#Constraint 18
mdl.add_constraints(mdl.sum(Z[k][i] for k in range(Total_T)) == 1 for i in range(Total_T))

# Constraint 19
mdl.add_constraints(mdl.sum(Z[k][i] for i in range(Total_T)) == 1 for k in range(Total_T))


# # Parameters
VW_temp = [[v + w]]
VW_temp = VW_temp*Total_T
VW = np.array(VW_temp) #eshape(Total_T,)


#Define S
S = np.array(mdl.continuous_var_list(Total_T, 0, inf, name='S')).reshape(Total_T,1)

 #Constraint 20

for k in range(Total_T-1):
    mdl.add_constraint(S[k][0] - S[k+1][0] <= -VW[k][0])

# # Constraint 21
mdl.add_constraint(S[Total_T-1][0] - (S[0][0] + obj_lambda) <=-VW[Total_T-1][0])

x_temp = x.reshape(Total_T,1)
print('x_temp',x_temp)

# Constraint 22
for k in range(Total_T):
    for i in range(Total_T):
         mdl.add_constraint(S[k][0] - x_temp[i][0] <= (1-Z[k][i])*bigM) #why x_temp? because it is the reshape of x

# Constraint 23
for k in range(Total_T):
    for i in range(Total_T):
        mdl.add_constraint(S[k][0] - x_temp[i][0] >= (Z[k][i]-1)*bigM)

mdl.minimize(obj_lambda)
mdl.print_information()
solver = mdl.solve() #(log_output=True)
if solver is not None:
    mdl.print_solution()
    miu = 1 / obj_lambda.solution_value
    print('obj_lamba=', obj_lambda.solution_value)
    print('miu =', miu)
else:
    print("Solver is error")
```

Here is the code of MIP 2:

```
import cplex
from docplex.mp.model import Model
import numpy as np

mdl = Model(name='Scheduling MILP 2')
inf = cplex.infinity
bigM= 10000

Total_P = 8 # number of places
Total_T = 6 # number of transitions

r1 = 100 #processing time for PM1 (second)
r2 = 200 #processing time for PM2 (second)

v = 3 #robot moving time (second)
w = 5 #loading or unloading time (second)

h = np.array([v+w,w+r1,v+w,w+r2,v+w,0,0,0]).reshape(Total_P,1)

#Parameter
AT =np.array([[1,-1,0,0,0,0],
              [0,1,-1,0,0,0],
              [0,0,1,-1,0,0],
              [0,0,0,1,-1,0],
              [0,0,0,0,1,-1],
              [0,-1,1,0,0,0],
              [0,0,0,-1,1,0],
              [-1,1,-1,1,-1,1]])
AT_temp = AT.transpose()

places = np.array(['p1','p2','p3','p4','p5','p6','p7','p8'])
P_conflict = np.empty((1,Total_P), dtype = object)
P_zero = np.empty((1,Total_P), dtype = object)

#Define the place without conflict place
CP = np.count_nonzero(AT, axis=1, keepdims=True) #calculate the nonzero elements for each row
P_conflict = []
P_zero = []

for a in range(0, len(CP)):
    if CP[a].item(0) > 2:
        P_conflict.append(places[a])
    else:
        P_zero.append(places[a])

print('p_zero', P_zero)

y = [ ] #miu

y = mdl.continuous_var(lb = 0, ub=inf, name='miu') #error: docplex.mp.utils.DOcplexException: Variable obj_lambda cannot be used as denominator of 1


x = np.array(mdl.continuous_var_list(Total_T, 0, inf, name='x')).reshape(Total_T,)
ind_x = np.where(AT[0] == 1)

def get_index_value(input):
  data = []
  for l in range(len(P_zero)):
    ind_x = np.where(AT[l] == input)
    get_value = x[ind_x]
    data.append(get_value)
  return data


x_in_hat = get_index_value(1)
x_out_hat = get_index_value(-1)





M0 = np.empty((Total_P,1), dtype = object)
for l in range(0,Total_P):
    M0[l][0]= mdl.integer_var(name='M0'+ str(',') + str(l+1))

M0_temp= M0.reshape(1,Total_P)
M0_final = M0_temp.tolist()*Total_T


for k in range(Total_T):
    for l in range(Total_P):
        if M0_final[k][l] is not None:
            mdl.add_constraint((M0_final[0][1] + M0_final[0][5]) == 1)
            mdl.add_constraint((M0_final[0][3] + M0_final[0][6]) == 1)
            mdl.add_constraint((M0_final[0][0] + M0_final[0][2] + M0_final[0][4] + M0_final[0][7]) == 2)


#constraint 30
for l in range(0,len(P_zero)): #only for P non conflict
    mdl.add_constraint(x_out_hat[l][0]-x_in_hat[l][0] >= h[l][0]*y - M0[l][0])

#Decision Var
Z = np.empty((Total_T, Total_T), dtype = object)
for k in range(Total_T):
    for i in range(Total_T):
         # if k == 0 and i == 0:
         #     Z[0][0]=1
         # else:
             Z[k][i] = mdl.binary_var(name='Z' + str(k+1) + str(',') + str(i+1))
#
storage_ZAT = []
for k in range(Total_T):
    ZAT = np.matmul(Z[k].reshape(1,Total_T),AT_temp)
    storage_ZAT.append(ZAT)    #storage_ZAT = np.append(storage_ZAT, ZAT, axis=0)

ZAT_final = np.asarray(storage_ZAT).reshape(Total_T,Total_P)



M = np.empty((Total_T, Total_P), dtype = object)

for k in range(0,Total_T):
    for l in range (0,Total_P):
        if k == Total_T-1:
            M[Total_T-1][l] = M0_final[0][l]
        else:
            M[k][l] = mdl.continuous_var(name='M' + str(k + 1) + str(',') + str(l + 1))

M_prev = np.empty((Total_T, Total_P), dtype = object)
if M is not None:
    for k in range(0,Total_T):
        for l in range (0,Total_P):
            if k is not 0:
                M_prev[k][l] = M[k-1][l]
            else:
                M_prev[0][l] = M0_final[0][l]
#
#Constraint 31
for k in range(Total_T):
  for l in range(Total_P):
        mdl.add_constraint(M[k][l] == M_prev[k][l] + ZAT_final[k][l])
#
#Constraint 32

mdl.add_constraints(mdl.sum(Z[k][i] for k in range(Total_T)) == 1 for i in range(Total_T))

# Constraint 33
mdl.add_constraints(mdl.sum(Z[k][i] for i in range(Total_T)) == 1 for k in range(Total_T))
# #
# # # # Parameters
VW_temp = [[v + w]]
VW_temp = VW_temp*Total_T
VW = np.array(VW_temp) #eshape(Total_T,)
#
S_hat = np.array(mdl.continuous_var_list(Total_T, 0, inf, name='S_hat')).reshape(Total_T,1)

#Constraint 34

for k in range(0,Total_T-1):
    if k < (Total_T-1):
        mdl.add_constraint(S_hat[k][0] - S_hat[k+1][0] <= -VW[k][0]*y)
    if k == (Total_T - 1):
        mdl.add_constraint(S_hat[k][0] - (S_hat[0][0] + 1) <= -VW[Total_T - 1][0] * y)# Constraint 35
#
#
x_temp_hat = x.reshape(Total_T,1)
#
# Constraint 36
for k in range(Total_T):
   for i in range(Total_T):
        mdl.add_constraint((S_hat[k][0] - x_temp_hat[i][0]) <= (1-Z[k][i])*bigM) #why x_temp? because it is the reshape of x


# Constraint 37
for k in range(Total_T):
     for i in range(Total_T):
        mdl.add_constraint((S_hat[k][0] - x_temp_hat[i][0]) >= (Z[k][i]-1)*bigM)



mdl.maximize(y)
mdl.print_information()
solver = mdl.solve()

if solver is not None:
    mdl.print_solution()
    obj_lambda = 1/y.solution_value
    print('miu =', y.solution_value)
    print('obj_lamba=', obj_lambda)
    print('M0 final=', M0_temp)
else:
    print("Solver is error")
```

In this case, could anyone tell me: did I define the M0 as a decision variable and put them into the constraints correctly, please?

Thank you.

Comment: We cannot tell if the model is correct from what you have given us. It looks like the values in M0 agree with the constraints that you have stated. We would need to see more of your model. Have you tried exporting the CPLEX model as e.g. an LP file to see what model is actually being created?

Comment: @TimChippingtonDerrick , I have just added both codes for MIP 1 and MIP 2. Do you mind to take a look, please? Thank you.